# ZScaler - cannot stop the service without passwords

Tags: service, disable, zscaler

I have installed a **ZScaler** client to be able to access my client's network remotely.
I got their username and passwords and it seems it is working, but it cut off me from my network and disabled many important services (according to the client's network policy), including my mail.
I do not have *ZScaler* Logout nor Uninstall password, but I have Administrator rights on my (own) computer.

I wanted to stop this service, but it is very tough (resilient to *Task Manager* and *Services*) operation.
That means when I kill ZScaler from Task Manager, it reappears. In *Services*, Stop command is disabled (grayed). I tried to kill it from command line (*taskkill PID*), but it reappears again!

(Luckily, I can access internet to write this question.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have found a very satisfying solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/xm2jng/comment/ivflauk/):

If you have admin rights, you can disable it under Powershell.

**List the status**:
Get-NetAdapterBinding -AllBindings -ComponentID ZS_ZAPPRD

**Disable**:
Get-NetAdapterBinding -AllBindings -ComponentID ZS_ZAPPRD | Disable-NetAdapterBinding

**Enable**:
Get-NetAdapterBinding -AllBindings -ComponentID ZS_ZAPPRD | Enable-NetAdapterBinding

---

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Does disabling persist through System Reboots?

Comment: This does not appear to work, there is no `NetAdapterBinding` with that name, or any name related to zscaler :/

Comment: It was working the time the question was asked, unfortunately currently it seems that ZScaler uses some different technique to intercept network traffic

Comment: It is possible that this is not working for a newer versions, I do not have it to check.

Comment: Can't believe it worked!  I ran Powershell as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

This command stopped working even running powershell as admin (Any help here guys !!!) :-

Get-NetAdapterBinding -AllBindings -ComponentID ZS_ZAPPRD | Disable-NetAdapterBinding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).